# issue with censor python script

Tags: python, user-input

I'm trying to write a file that censors the word "winter" but for some reason my code isn't working although I have no errors. Help!

```
filename = input("Enter file name (without extension): ")
file1 = filename+".txt"
file2 = filename+"_censored.txt"

word = input("Enter the word you are searching for: ")
#In this case, the input would be "winter"

print("\nLooping through the file, line by line.")

in_text_file = open(file1, "r")

out_text_file = open(file2,"w")

for line in in_text_file:
    print(line)
out_text_file.write(line)

n = [ ]

def censor(word, filename):
   for i in text.split(''):
        if i == word:
            i = "*" * len(word)
            n.append(i)
        else:
            n.append(i)
            return ' '.join(n)

in_text_file.close()
out_text_file.close()
```

Comment: start by fixing your indentation

Comment: Your indentation is wonky.  Could you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

One way to censor it would be to just run `replace` on the read file.

A simple example:

```
file1 = open("filetobecensored.txt")
file2 = open("winter_censored.txt", "w")
word = "winter"
file2.write(file1.read().replace(word, "*"*len(word)))
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You lost the formatting when posting the question, so it's hard to see exactly what your code looks like. Please edit the question to fix that.

But my initial guess would be that the `censor` function is never called. You just declare it, but it doesn't run.